# Bootstrap JS apparently being overwritten by webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

### Description

I noticed when using a JavaScript file (e.g. `app/javascript/packs/custom.js`), Bootstrap jquery events like `shown.bs.modal`, does not work. I want to use different js files for different pages, but it does not work well with Bootstrap js functions, because of some unexpected behavior. I think I missed something in my app installation that is causing this issue.

### Environment

jQuery and Bootstrap were installeb by: `yarn add bootstrap@4.3.1 jquery popper.js`

- Rails version: 6.0.3.4
- Bootstrap version: 4.3.1
- jQuery version: 3.5.1
- `config/webpack/environment.js`

```js
...
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
...
```

- `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```js
...
import 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap'
import '../stylesheets/application.scss'
```

- `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

- `app/javascript/packs/custom.js`

```js
ready = function() {
    console.log('document loaded');                  

    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        console.log('a button was pressed');
    });

    $('#testModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        console.log('testModal shown');
    });
}

$(document).ready(ready);
```

### Actual behavior

In the page, Bootstrap styles work, modal shows up normally, but I can only see the 'document loaded' and 'a button was pressed' prints on the console. Inspecting the JavaScript file generated by Webpacker for `custom.js`, I see it is including jQuery again. With that, I assume that Bootstrap js functions are being overwritten.

### Expected behavior

`shown.bs.modal` and other Bootstrap events callbacks are called, and Webpack does not include jQuery again for external js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the actual issue. I noticed that `config/webpack/environment.js` is including jQuery for every processed file. So the solution is to erase jQuery definitions on that file and manually define jQuery on `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```js
...
import jquery from "jquery"
window.$ = window.jquery = jquery
import "bootstrap"

import '../stylesheets/application.scss'
```

So now jQuery is only included in the default application.js file.